# emacs tune helm mode to focus on the first option.

Tags: emacs, emacs-helm

helm package works great for listing all options and completions. One thing that bothers for a long time is that the first available option is not automatically chosen. the following screenshot shows the problem[image]

when I type "sc", I want the first option "scratch" being highlighted so I can just press enter to switch to it, not C-n then enter.

Anyone know how to tune this performance? Thank you

Comment: It looks like you're using some custom settings of `helm`. The default behavior already does what you ask.

Comment: @abo-abo, that's what i thought, thank you, i will try to correct it.

Comment: turns out that I didn't enable the helm-mini with C-x b keybinding.   (global-set-key (kbd "C-x b") 'helm-mini)